# Can I use Firebase job dispatcher library using eclipse IDE

Tags: android, android-service, android-memory, firebase-job-dispatcher

I came to know about firebase job dispatcher and I would like to know whether I can use this using eclipse oxygen.
Right now am using eclipse for android development.

If so then how can I get the jar file for this, or do i need something else.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: Can I ask why you are still using an IDE that is no longer supported?

Comment: An IDE has nothing to do with what libraries the app you build can use.

Comment: @tyczj am connected to an old version, tfs that is not support in android studio

Comment: @GabeSechan , So how can i import firebase dispatcher library without gradle, I mean to ask how to get the jar file basically?

Comment: You probably want the aar.  Grab it from the maven repository.  Or use Gradle with Eclipse, its entirely possible.  What you're really asking isn't how to use this library with android studio, you're asking how to use Maven packages with whatever build system you're using.